# Tailwind safelist patterns for multiple patterns?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to use safelist patterns (formerly whitelist patterns) with Tailwind CSS V3.1.6 and have the following. It's not working, but essentially I'm trying to safelist all values beginning with `bg-`, `text-` and `border-`

```
safelist: [
  // Retain all classes starting with...,
  {
    pattern: /bg-/,
    pattern: /text-/,
    pattern: /border-/,
  },
],
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this : https://github.com/spatie/tailwind-safelist-generator

Comment: Hey, I beleive that's for older versions, as it's using 'purge' instead of 'content'? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @IharAliakseyenka - works like a charm! If you want to add an answer I'll mark as accepted. Not sure why this isn't clearer in the docs?

Answer (score 16):

You can safelist multiple entrances within an array of objects like

```js
safelist: [
  {pattern: /bg-./},
  {pattern: /text-./},
  {pattern: /border-./},
]
```

but in your case it would be shorter to use pipe sign "|"

```js
safelist: [
  {pattern: /(bg|text|border)-./}
]
```

More about safelisting with regular expressions can be found [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want with any pattern just one liner

```
      pattern: /([a-zA-Z]+)-./,
```